# How to generate mousedown or keypress event programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am developing a chrome extension that runs some javascript on a particular web page.

I want to simulate a click action on the google docs presentation view page's 'prev', 'next' toolbar.
Unfortunately, both are  tags with onmousedown events corresponding to obfuscated javascript.

If they were anchors,
document.getElementById("ToolbarNext").onclick(); works. However, the same for onmousedown does not seem to work, probably because it requires mouse co-ordinates, etc.
How do I generate this event?

An other option is to simulate a keypress 'j' or 'k' on the DOM. I tried a few options but could not figure that out either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `dispatchEvent/fireEvent` methods

Answer (score -1):

You can collect the function that is attached to the onmousedown and execute it.
However you'll have to re-create the `event` object if you need it:

```
<input type="button" onmousedown="console.log('mousedown')" value="click me" />
<script>
    var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0],
        fn = inp.onmousedown;
        fn({target:inp/*, other properties of the event object if needed */});
</script>
```

Comment: the exact code is:
`var next = document.getElementById("ToolbarNext");
var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
next.fireEvent(e);`